# Assignments different elements into same <div> tag

Tags: php, html

My PHP code generates the elements of class="error". I want all such generated elements to lie within the "class1" div tag for which I need to know when to close it by "

```
<?php
foreach ($myArr as $i => $value) {
$id = some_function($value);
if ($id == NULL ) {
    print "<div class="error"><b>$value</b> could not be processed.</div>"
   }
} else { ...
 }
?>

<div class="class2">
</div>
```

Now, I don't know when to put the last  tag to close ... **Solution1:** I could always search my array for the last "NULL" value and for that that key alone I could close the tag, but **Is there any other better trick with which I can assign all the elements that are generated to go under a particular  tag**?

Thanks,
John

Comment: Reason I downvoted: It's unclear exactly what the question is. Please clarify the question.

Comment: I hope I clarified it to you sir :)

Comment: Inspect the dom tree and append the html where you need

Comment: Thanks for editing, but I'm still not sure I understand. If I am correct in understanding it, then you should be able to just echo out the closing `</div>` after the foreach loop ends.

Comment: Also, it would help to make it more readable if you gave your code indentation.

Comment: The OP want instead of ECHO the span into the nowhere, to print it within the div

Comment: In that case you can just move the PHP snippet inside the div... No need to involve the DOM tree.

Comment: It is not said that the div is on the same page or it's done by some module which contains the php

Answer (score 0):

You should try something like that to put the div closing tag:

```
foreach ($array as $i => $value) 
{
    $id = some_function($value);
    if ($id == NULL ) {
        echo "<li><b>".$value"</b> could not be processed.</br></li>";
    } else { 
      ...
    }

    if ($i == end(array_keys($array))){ // last element of array
        echo "</div>";
    } 
}
```

For your second question, if you want to assign certain elements to go under a particular tag, PHP is not done for that. Of course you can do it, but manually.

You should use Javascript (with JQuery http://api.jquery.com/append/) to append content easily in elements (don't know if that correspond to what you need).